# Why do two variable share the same address?

Tags: c, variables, gcc, overlap, memory-address

Using gcc version 4.0.1, on an iMac, OsX 10.5,

*some variables have been assigned the same address
as the second group of elements within a two dimentional array.*

What should I do to prevent the compiler from assigning addresses in this way?

Included is a program which demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long a[1][10];
long b;
long c;

int main()
{
    printf( "Address of a[0][0]: %p\n", &a[0][0] );
    printf( "Address of a[0][1]: %p\n\n", &a[0][1] );
    printf( "Address of a[1][0]: %p\n", &a[1][0] );
    printf( "Address of a[1][1]: %p\n\n", &a[1][1] );
    printf( "Address of b: %p\n", &b );
    printf( "Address of c: %p\n\n", &c );
}
```

#### Output:

```
Address of a[0][0]: 0x2040
Address of a[0][1]: 0x2044

Address of a[1][0]: 0x2068
Address of a[1][1]: 0x206c

Address of b: 0x2068
Address of c: 0x206c
```

I have a 'verbose' description of the gcc output if it is wanted.

Comment: Simply put, that code is accessing garbage(out of bound entries) and garbage value can be anything.

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan <pedantic>It's not accessing them, but it's invoking UB by calculating pointers which are out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 5):

Because you define the array as `long a[1][10]`. That means that you can only access `a[0][N]`

Remember, when you define the size of the array, you can index up to `N-1`.

Answer (score 4):

You're printing out the address of something that doesn't exist.

printf( "Address of a[1][0]: %p\n", &a[1][0] );

Since you declared `a` as `long a[1][10];`, there is no `&a[1][0]`, that's one past the dimension of your array. Only `a[0][0 to 9]` exists.

Answer (score 1):

`long a[1][10]` will reserve space for 10 long values on the stack.
`a` will point to the first element.
`long b` will reserve space for one long value and also `long c` does.
`b` will be directly after `a` and `c` directly after `b`.

`a[1][0]` will point to the element that lies 10 times 1 times the size of a long value after the first element of `a`. Here this will be `b`.

`a[1][1]` will point to the element that lies  ( 10 times 1 plus 1 ) times the size of a long value behind the first element of `a`. In this case this will be `c`.

This is the reason you observe the same addresses.

Answer (score 0):

nos, & *Steffen*,

Thankyou for your timely responses...I see the (now obvious) error of my ways!

I learnt programming using Qbasic, where;

```
DIM a(1,10)  AS INTEGER  'the subscripts give the maximum array value...
                         'and not the number of elements in the array.
```

...is a 2 * 11 array.

I and am in the painful process of trying to 'convert' to C.

William.